# Does Passing by Reference Avoid Creating New Variable?

Tags: php, oop

If I pass a variable or object to a function call by reference, I would imagine it avoids creating a second object in memory, thus preserving resources? For example:

```
<?php

class CoolObject
{
    // Have some properties here

    public function __construct()
    {
       // Do some stuff
    }

    public function test()
    {
       echo("Test");
    }
}

function doSomething(&$param)
{
   // Calls original instance, still only one object in memory
   $param->test();

   // Does this create a second instance in memory, or just assign
   // the reference?
   $newObj = $param;
}

// Create 1st instance of object in memory
$myObj = new CoolObject;

// Do a test to determine number of instances created
doSomething($myObj);

?>
```

When I assigned the "by reference" variable to $newObj, did it create a new one in memory bringing the count up to two, or did it just pass the reference still leaving only one object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass in a variable by reference, you are correct in that it does not duplicate the object. Instead, it copies the pointer to the object. So, while it uses some memory, it's only the amount of memory equal to the size of a pointer.

When you create another variable that points to the same object, again, you're copying the pointer, with the same consequences as above.

As far as reference counting and objects, each time you copy the pointer, the reference counter gets incremented.

Only when the reference count is zero does the object get freed.

Answer (score 2):

The general concept of references and values of object is generally poorly understood.  An object variable contains a handle to the object, so if `$x` is some object and we assign it to a couple of other variables, say

```
$x  = new Jim;
$d  = $x;
$e &= $x;
```

the 2dn and 3rd statements are cheap assignments as all these do is to assign an object handle.  This is of the same order of cost as `$y=5`, for example.

`$d->someproperty` and `$d->somemethod()` refer to the same as as `$x->someproperty` and `$x->somemethod()`.  Ditto for `$e`.  The difference occurs when you do new assignments to `$d` and `$e`:

```
$d  = new Fred;
$e = $someotherobject;
```

`$d` now refers to a different object from `$x`, but `$x` is otherwise unchanged.  With the `$e` assignment `$e` still refers to the same object as `$x` but *both now refer* to a `Fred`.  This has created a side-effect, deliberate or (more usually) accidental.  Doing this via function arguments is just the same.

**Moral:** Don't use references with objects unless you *really* understand what you are doing, and why, and what the pitfalls are.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that if you pass by reference, you don't create a new variable, but changes made to the variable you use in that function would also effect the original variable that you passed in.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. What about the second portion...is $newObj a new instance or a "pointer" to $myObj?

Answer (score 0):

Objects are always passed by reference. Only simple vars are usualy passed by reference if you explisitely use the `&` sign. so `$myObj` is a "pointer"

Comment: That first sentence was what I needed for a Google search. Here is what I learned http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php